# Extract Text from Multipage Attachment PDF Using Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, text, blob, ocr

I have a Gmail attachment PDF with multiple scanned pages.  When I use Google Apps Script to save the blob from the attachment to a Drive file, open the PDF manually from Google Drive, then select Open With Google Docs, all of the text from the PDF is displayed as a Google Doc.  However, when I save the blob as a Google Doc with OCR, only the text from the image on the first page is saved to a Doc, accessed either manually or by code.

The code to get the blob and process it is:

```
function getAttachments(desiredLabel, processedLabel, emailQuery){
    // Find emails
    var threads = GmailApp.search(emailQuery);
    if(threads.length > 0){
        // Iterate through the emails
        for(var i in threads){
            var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
            for(var j in mesgs){
                var processingMesg = mesgs[j];
                var attachments = processingMesg.getAttachments();
                var processedAttachments = 0;
                // Iterate through attachments
                for(var k in attachments){
                    var attachment = attachments[k];
                    var attachmentName = attachment.getName();
                    var attachmentType = attachment.getContentType();
                    // Process PDFs
                    if (attachmentType.includes('pdf')) {
                        processedAttachments += 1;
                        var pdfBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
                        var filename = attachmentName + " " + processedAttachments;
                        processPDF(pdfBlob, filename);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function processPDF(pdfBlob, filename){
  // Saves the blob as a PDF.
  // All pages are displayed if I click on it from Google Drive after running this script.
  let pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);
  pdfFile.setName(filename);
  // Saves the blob as an OCRed Doc.
  let resources = {
    title: filename,
    mimeType: "application/pdf"
  };
  let options = {
    ocr: true,
    ocrLanguage: "en"
  };
  let file = Drive.Files.insert(resources, pdfBlob, options);
  let fileID = file.getId();
  // Open the file to get the text.
  // Only the text of the image on the first page is available in the Doc.
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileID);
  let docText = doc.getBody().getText();
}
```

If I try to use Google Docs to read the PDF without OCR directly, I get Exception: Invalid argument, for example:

```
DocumentApp.openById(pdfFile.getId());
```

How do I get the text from all of the pages of the PDF?

Comment: Can you provide the code wth which you get the pdfBlob?

Comment: I added the code to get the attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DocumentApp.openById` is a method that can only be used for Google Docs documents
- `pdfFile` can only be "opened" with the [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) - `DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId());`
- Opening a file with `DriveApp` allows you to use the [following](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) methods on the file
- When it comes to OCR conversion, your code works for me correctly to convert all pages of a PDF document to Google Docs, so you error source is likely come from  the attachment itself / the way you retrieve the blob
- Mind that OCR conversion is not good at preserving formatting, so a two page PDF might be collapsed into a one-page Docs - depneding on the formatting of the PDF

Comment: I only need the text.  The formatting is irrelevant.  The blob has all of the data

Comment: I did manage to get a binary structure that showed a binary structure with pages, but that doesn't appear to be accessible, for example, <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 34 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 108 0 R/ViewerPreferences 109 0 R>>. 
 <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>, if there were some way to access the PDF by page maybe that would work.

Comment: This is not a coding issue. I finally figured out that I was looking at the wrong reference document when checking the output. When I tried another multipage PDF, it read all the text. NIC error - Not In Computer.